# ZfcUser registration complications

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

My problem is that ZfcUser module isnt working properly at OpenShift hosting. Locally on my PC everything is OK i can register and log in but uploaded its not possible. There is no even errors showing up. Everything it says is "Authentication failed. Please try again."

My configs seems to be ok i've tried so many different combinations but looks like scipts have access to database (when i change to something random it shows exceptions etc.).

What i've figured out is that when i submit the register form it passes but it is not adding the user to database it is empty. Other thing is that even the "login_after_reigster" option is "false" it still try to login after "passed" registration.

Everything is the same (expect database configuration) as local (where it works) but not working on remote host

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the local database and import it on the server! I had this problem too, and this seems to resolve it.

Or, if you can, run in the console

`php /path/to/public/folder/index.php orm:schema-tool:create --force`

Then it will work!